# no implicit conversion of Symbol into String rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem when deleting/creating a record in the model Calendar, but only when I use `flash[:alert] = "Notification deleted"`. It's happening only in this model. Basically if I use

```
def destroy
      if @calendar.destroy
        redirect_to calendars_path
      else
        redirect_to :back, :flash => { :error => "Failed to delete!" }
      end
    end
```

everything is working fine, but if I add `flash[:alert] = "Notification deleted"` after the `redirect_to` like this:

```
def destroy
      if @calendar.destroy
        redirect_to calendars_path, flash[:alert] = "Notification deleted"
      else
        redirect_to :back, :flash => { :error => "Failed to delete!" }
      end
    end
```

I get  `TypeError in CalendarsController#destroy`. I use flash[:alert] in many controllers and it's working, but this one has that error.

I don't know how to track the error further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flash[:alert] = "Notification deleted"` will return the string. That means when it runs it will turn into

```
redirect_to calendars_path, "Notification deleted"
```

Which is invalid according to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html). All params except the first must be key-value.

Change to

```
def destroy
  if @calendar.destroy
    redirect_to calendars_path, flash: { alert: "Notification deleted" }
    # You can omit the flash key as well
    # redirect_to calendars_path, alert: "Notification deleted"
  else
    redirect_to :back, :flash => { :error => "Failed to delete!" }
  end
end
```

Or move the assignment to before the redirection.

```
def destroy
  if @calendar.destroy
    flash[:alert] = "Notification deleted"
    redirect_to calendars_path
  else
    redirect_to :back, :flash => { :error => "Failed to delete!" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working. No idea how I missed that. I have it the same(right way) in other controllers, but now that it happened could you explain why it's working like that and not how I tried it here?